# pdo fetch object?

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a better way to return object of db result?

I am a aware "`return $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'modelClassName');`" but it only work on fetchall function?

```
class modelArea extends Model {

    public $areaID;
    public $postcode;

    public static function find($condition, $parameters) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM area WHERE " . $condition;

        $statement = self::getDb()->prepare($query);
        if (!$statement->execute($parameters))
            return false;

        $query = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $a = new modelArea();

        $a->areaID = $query['areaID'];
        $a->postcode = $query['postcode'];

        return $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also just extend the model class from ArrayObject and pass an array to the constructor or `->exchangeArray`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`PDOStatement::fetchObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) method does what you want.

You can use it like:

```
$a = $statement->fetchObject('modelArea');
```

This will result in `$a` being an object of class `modelArea`, equivalent to the code you give.

Comment: Thanks, how about this? return $statement->fetchObject('modelArea');

Answer (score 1):

You could create a static method of the `modelArea` class (or a separate factory class) and call:

```
modelArea::createFromArray($query);
```

or even have one that returns an array of `modelArea` objects

```
modelArea::createFromStatement($stmt);
```